# Answer early, answer often!

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions, beta

We currently have 18 questions per day which is excellent regarding the quantity content is generated on our little private beta.

But we now have to transit from quantity to quality. [The answer rate is 1.5](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704/ethereum) <del>and only 87% of the questions are answered</del>. *Update: Answer rate is not at 92%!*

Let's push these values to **3 answers per question** and a 99% answer rate to make this a healthy beta.

Best place to start is:

- **24** questions with [no answers at all](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- **28** questions with [no upvoted or accepted answers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)
- **199** questions with [less than 2 answers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A..1%20%26%20closed%3Ano%20%26%20duplicate%3Ano)
- **288** questions with [less than 3 answers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A..2%20%26%20closed%3Ano%20%26%20duplicate%3Ano)

Happy answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about you but here's *my strategy* ([copied from meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/226837)).

1. **Post quality answers.** This should be numbered 1, 2 and 3. But a good answer will more often than not trump a fast answer. Though there are cases where it does not.
2. **Monitor the [frontpage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) and the [new questions list.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions)** Learn their cache time and refresh accordingly or use the tag pages ([Example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eth+or+geth?sort=newest)) to get live updates on new questions.
3. **Setup a good but short list of Interesting and Ignored tags.** For example I have [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity), [smart-contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-contracts), [contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-design), and [dapp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapp) as interesting tags. This will help you see questions, which you can answer, quicker.
4. **Avoid Wall of Text questions.** They take way too much effort for little reward. And usually are syntax errors or bad structure.
5. **Post an answer even though the question has 1–2 or even 3 answers.** In these cases, take your time and answer well. This will usually net you a good sum of rep.
6. **Learn when to edit.** Post a short answer at first and then edit. You have <5 minutes to make that answer shine.
7. **Be humble, thorough and fair.** There are a lot of smart people out there and many will know much more than you about the subject. Be thorough in the code you post, check it for syntax errors and make sure it fits the question. And if you see that the correct answer is already there, upvote it, that person deserves the rep.

Comment: You have <5 minutes to make that answer shine  <--- ?