# New user "recruitment" campaign?

Tags: discussion, users, new-users

According to the [Area 51 stats for Ethereum](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704/ethereum), we seem to be doing fine on all stats except those related to number of users. I came here as a result of an announcement on /r/ethereum about a month back. Would it be time for another recruitment campaign? If so, what would be sources of good candidates?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit, nevermind, we just entered public beta!**

I don't have the feeling we have an issue with (missing) users yet. This is actually an advantage during the *private* part of the *beta* stage.

Now we have to focus on:

- **10** high quality questions per day, to keep content coming
- **3** high quality [answers per question](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/87), to keep the answer rate above **2.5** (count: **25** answers per day)
- **all** the [votes you can spend per day](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/87), to ensure enough users recieve reputation
- organize questions in [well defined tags](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/87) and wikis, to save a lot of work later

The user base and page hits per day will come as soon as we transit into the *public beta* phase and google will yield the good content we generated during the private beta.

Answer (score 1):

There's also probably a way to ping users who "committed"?

From sidebar of http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704/ethereum

committed users

- 292 users committed
- 53.8% signed up for beta
- 0% fulfilled commitment