# How to list all questions with less than 3 answers?

Tags: support, answers, unanswered-questions

As our answer rate is [really](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/87), [really](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704/ethereum) poor, currently at 1.5 answers per question, I am wondering, is there a way to list all questions with less than 3 answers?

- I've seen there is the [unanswered](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/unanswered) tab, listing questions without upvoted or accepted answers.
- I've seen there is the [no answers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) tab, listing questions without any answers.
- One could search for [answers:0](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0) to find all questions without answers.
- One could search for [answers:3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A3) to find all questions with 3 or more answers.

But how about 0, 1 and 2 answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this in the [advanced searching help](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/searching):
[answers..2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A..2)

Comment: wow super cool!

Answer (score 1):

I created some queries on data-se.

1. [high voted unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/query/433545/find-high-voted-unanswered-questions)
2. [top questions by view count](http://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/query/433542/top-10k-questions-by-view-count-questions-only)

they might be helpful in the future to promote content.